# Laravel migrates table correctly but can't talk to DB through Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So I have a almost bare bones Laravel 5.4 application. I ran `php artisan make:auth` to scaffold the auth system. I was able to migrate the users table no problem

```
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
```

However when I try to register it throws a SQL can't connect error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = email@email.com)
```

How could this be happening if I'm able to migrate the tables successfully? Even after the registrion method throws that error I'm still able to rollback the migration:

```
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
```

And re-migrate the tables:

```
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
```

So I know the PostgreSQL server is up and running.

SMALL UPDATE
The same issue happens with Laravel 5.3 so it has nothing to do with the recent release of 5.4

Comment: maybe you have different environment for console and web application

Comment: Are you sure everything has been setup correctly in your .env file? Might be an error in your username, password, host or whatever? Does the db user have the rights to query the users table?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `.env`file you should check your `.env` file where you haven't specified username or password so it will take `homestead` from `database.php`

check your `.env`'s DB section

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=my ip //localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDBname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=my pass
```